# Why does colorist keep returning "None" after it completes a string conversion to color

Tags: python-3.x, text, colors

I am starting to use the import of "Colorist" and I get some strange results...

when I type the following into the command prompt, I get this...

In [171]: c.red("hello world. ")
hello world.

In [172]: print( c.red("hello world. "))
hello world.
None

In [172]: print( c.red("hello world. "))
hello world.
None

What is the "None? And how do I get rid of it?

I tried different ways, but they didn't work or they came back with "None".

Comment: why do you think you need `print`? In your first line `hello world` is already printed without `print`

Answer (score 0):

I want to print multiple different colors in a single string of text. That's why the first command worked. I think I may have to create an import that creates a set of colors with escape codes instead.

i.e. But for now...

```py
print("\033[0;34;40m True to the name \033[0;31;40m Porsche \033[0;37;40m")
```